# make my program wait for an xmlhttprequest to finish

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i've probably complicated this issue for myself..i have 2 XMLHTTPRequests in my page, the first request gets some data from an API and then i want to fill my elements with this data, now the issue is one of the fields of my elements needs to send a second request to a different endpoint to get its data using one of the values received from the first request, but it's always filled with **undefined**

i understand that's due to the async nature of the request where the site will continue loading and won't wait for the request to complete so i tried making the second request synchronous but the same thing happens (only now the site freezes for a second), i tried using async await as well but my text editor said that "await has no effect on the type of this expression" and i'm completely stuck..

i believe it's due to my lack of experience and understanding of the asynchronous javascript (this is my first application using it)..

here is my code:

```
let ourGrid=document.getElementById("res");
let searchValue;
function search(){
    searchValue=document.getElementById("search").value;
    getFoods(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=${searchValue}&number=2&apiKey=${apikey}`);
}

function getFoods(url){
    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType='json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange=()=>{
        if(xhr.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            setFoods(xhr.response);
        }else{
            return "error";
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET',url);
    xhr.send();
}

function setFoods(json){
    if(json.length==0){
        alert(`no results found for ${searchValue}`);
    }else{
    ourGrid.innerHTML=json.map(foodLogic).join("");
    }
    
}

function foodLogic(foodItem){
     return `<div class="imageItem"><img src="${foodItem.image}"></div>
     <div class="infoItem"><h2>${foodItem.title}</h2>
     <p class="summary">${requestSummary(foodItem.id)}</p>
     <p class="more"><a href="./moreInfo.html" target="_blank">More</a></p></div>
     ` 
}

function requestSummary(id){
let url2=`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${id}/summary?apiKey=${apikey}`;
let xhr2=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.onreadystatechange=()=>{
  if(xhr2.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
    return returnSummary(JSON.stringify(xhr2.response));
    }
  }    
xhr2.open('GET',url2,false);
xhr2.send();
}

function returnSummary(json){
    return json.summary;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried promises? or Callbacks?

Comment: i wanted to try using a promise but i didn't understand how to make it work, the promise takes an executor function with a resolve and reject parameters..i didn't know where/how to write my own functionality inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can also use promises or callbacks. Call the second function after first one is done and pass the data to only one function that changes everything.

Get the summary here itself and pass to next function.

```js
function getFoods(url){
    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType='json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange=()=>{
        if(xhr.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            let summary = requestSummary(xhr.response.id);
            setFoods(xhr.response, summary); //pass summary
        }else{
            return "error";
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET',url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Now you will have access to summary in `setfoods`, use it however you like

```js
function setFoods(json,summary){
    if(json.length==0){
        alert(`no results found for ${searchValue}`);
    }else{
    ourGrid.innerHTML=json.map(foodLogic).join("");
    // Here you have access to summary, use it however you like
    } 
}
```

Comment: it returns 404 error to the summary request in this code

Comment: i don't know why exactly but the response id returns undefined and that's why i get 404..it worked fine before

Comment: i got it now, the request returns a json array with multiple objects, i'd have to iterate over each object to get its id and then send the second request which means i can't use the request like that

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I decided to store all the id's and then after the site and the initial stuff from first request were loaded I would go and request the id's one by one using fetch request (because the ajax didn't work, I went through a tutorial for it) and then reach to every summary element in the html and fill it in order.

Code:

```
let ourGrid=document.getElementById("res");
let searchValue;
let arrid=[];
function search(){
    searchValue=document.getElementById("search").value;
    getFoods(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=${searchValue}&number=2&apiKey=${key}`);
}

function getFoods(url){
    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType='json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange=()=>{
        if(xhr.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE){ 
            setFoods(xhr.response);
        }else{
            return "error";
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET',url);
    xhr.send();
}

function setFoods(json){
    if(json.length==0){
        alert(`no results found for ${searchValue}`);
    }else{
    ourGrid.innerHTML=json.map(foodLogic).join("");
    doId();
    } 
}


function foodLogic(foodItem){
        arrid.push(foodItem.id);
     return `<div class="imageItem"><img src="${foodItem.image}"></div>
     <div class="infoItem"><h2>${foodItem.title}</h2>
     <p class="summary"></p>
     <p class="more"><a href="./moreInfo.html" target="_blank">More</a></p></div>
     ` 
}

function doId(){
    let duh=ourGrid.getElementsByClassName("infoItem");
    for(let i=0;i<arrid.length;i++){
        fetch(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${arrid[i]}/summary?apiKey=${key}`)
        .then(res=>{return res.json()})
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
            duh[i].getElementsByClassName("summary")[0].innerHTML=data.summary;
        });
    }
}
```